# Retrieve child nodes values

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

```
private void dislpay() {
        try {   
            File fXmlFile = new File("/data/data/com.example.addnode/Add.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("details");
            for (int temp = 0; temp <= nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                    String a=eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(temp).getTextContent().toString();
                    String b=eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(temp).getTextContent().toString();
                    String c=eElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname").item(temp).getTextContent().toString();

                    System.out.println(a);
                    System.out.println(b);
                    System.out.println(c);
                }
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

XML is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <user>
       <details id="1">
         <firstname>JOHN</firstname>
         <lastname>R</lastname>
         <nickname>JJ</nickname>
       </details>
       <details>
         <firstname>NOMAN</firstname>
         <lastname>K</lastname>
         <nickname>NK</nickname>
       </details>    
    </user>
```

Expected output:

```
JOHN R JJ
NOMAN K NK
```

Current Output is:

```
JOHN R JJ
```

I want to display all the values of child node(details) but when i execute the application it show only first three value not all.I am learning XML so i don not have much knowledge about XML. so please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your existing code, correcting your mistake....,

```
//Remove = otherwise loop will run 3 times and you will get null pointer exception
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++)

// Replace temp with 0 here because temp is increasing with your for loop and this is first node of this element always

                String a=eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent().toString();
                String b=eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent().toString();
                String c=eElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname").item(0).getTextContent().toString();
```

For your ease,
I had prepared this DOM parser by myself, using recursion which will parse your xml without having knowledge of single tag. It will give you each node's text content if exist, in a sequence. You can remove commented section in following code to get node name also. Hope it would help.

```
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;  
    import java.io.FileInputStream;  
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

     import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;  
     import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;  
     import org.w3c.dom.Document;  
     import org.w3c.dom.Node;  
     import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;  



    public class RecDOMP {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
            dbf.setValidating(false); 
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();   

    // replace following  path with your input xml path  
             Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File  ("D:\\ambuj\\ATT\\apip\\APIP_New.xml")));  

    // replace following  path with your output xml path 
             File OutputDOM = new File("D:\\ambuj\\ATT\\apip\\outapip1.txt");
                FileOutputStream fostream = new FileOutputStream(OutputDOM);
                OutputStreamWriter oswriter = new OutputStreamWriter (fostream);
                BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter(oswriter);

                // if file doesnt exists, then create it
                if (!OutputDOM.exists()) {
                    OutputDOM.createNewFile();}


                visitRecursively(doc,bwriter);
                bwriter.close(); oswriter.close(); fostream.close();

                System.out.println("Done");
    }
    public static void visitRecursively(Node node, BufferedWriter bw) throws IOException{  

                 // get all child nodes  
             NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();                                  
             for (int i=0; i<list.getLength(); i++) {          
                     // get child node              
           Node childNode = list.item(i);  
           if (childNode.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
           {
       //System.out.println("Found Node: " + childNode.getNodeName()           
        //   + " - with value: " + childNode.getNodeValue()+" Node type:"+childNode.getNodeType()); 

       String nodeValue= childNode.getNodeValue();
       nodeValue=nodeValue.replace("\n","").replaceAll("\\s","");
       if (!nodeValue.isEmpty())
       {
           System.out.println(nodeValue);
           bw.write(nodeValue);
           bw.newLine();
       }
           }
           visitRecursively(childNode,bw);  

                }         

         }  

    }
```